# Verifying if these basis are positive or negative?

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

> Verify if the basis $E=(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ and $F=(f_1,f_2,f_3)$ are positive or negative with:
>
> $$f_1=e_1\quad \quad\quad\quad\quad f_2=e_2+e_3\quad \quad \quad\quad \quad f_3=e_1+e_2 $$

I did the following:

- I assumed that $e_1=(1,0,0),\;e_2=(0,1,0),\; e_3=(0,0,1)$.
- Then $f_1=(1,0,0),\; f_2=(0,1,1), \; f_3=(1,1,0)$.
- Then I took the determinant $[e_1,e_2,e_3]=1$ and $[f_1,f_2,f_3]=-1$.

Is this procedure enough to verify if they are positive or negative? I'm not sure if assuming that first step is legitimate.

Comment: You can't say if the bases are positive of negative, you only can say whether two bases have the same orientation or not. So here you can conclude one of $E$ and $F$  is  positive, and the other  negative.

Comment: @Bernard I don't get it. I found one of them being positive and other being negative. How are thet both positive? I am aware that re-arranging the order of the vectors in the determinant changes the signal. Is that it?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your data. I edited my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh Jesus! If you take two bases $E$ and $F$, the matrix of change from $E$ to $F$ is given by: $$M_{EF} = [{\rm id}]_{FE}.$$Then $E$ and $F$ have the same orientation if $\det M_{EF} > 0$. Note that this determinant won't ever be zero (why?). What you did is valid, but your notation was sloppy: ${\bf e}_1 = (1,0,0)$ is being used to mean $[{\bf e}_1]_E = (1,0,0)$, [etc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector) - the vector ${\bf e}_1$ is not necessarily the vector $(1,0,0) = {\bf i}$.

A sure-fire way to do this is to compute $[{\rm id}]_{EF}$. $$\begin{cases} {\rm id}({\bf f}_1) = {\bf f}_1 = 1\cdot {\bf e}_1 + 0 \cdot {\bf e}_2 + 0\cdot {\bf e}_3 \\ {\rm id}({\bf f}_2) = {\bf f}_2 = 0\cdot {\bf e}_1 + 1 \cdot {\bf e}_2 + 1\cdot {\bf e}_3 \\ {\rm id}({\bf f}_3) = {\bf f}_3 = 1\cdot {\bf e}_1 + 1 \cdot {\bf e}_2 + 0\cdot {\bf e}_3 \end{cases}$$

Building the matrix: $$M_{EF} = [{\rm id}]_{FE} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \implies \det M_{EF} = -1 <0,$$ so they have opposite orientations. Note, though, that "positive" and "negative" orientations only make sense w.r.t. a fixed basis in space - usually the canonical basis. If you define $E \sim F$ if and only if $\det M_{EF} > 0$, you get an equivalence relation. Since the determinant is always positive or negative, we only get two equivalence classes. Pick the class of the canonical basis and call it "positive".

Comment: I'm sorry but are you sure your second matrix is correct? Because the product of the two transition matrices is supposed to be $I_n$ right? Your matrices don't seem to give that... am I misunderstanding something?